# Deploy ASP.NET WebForms to server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, publishing, web-publishing

I have ASP.NET WEB forms project.I also use TFS to sharing code.

1)First i make Publish on the project

```
    -Create own Profile on publishing
```

2)Visual studio create Deployment folder where i have files:

```
   Project.Web.deploy.cmd

   Project.Web.deploy-readme.txt

   Project.Web.SetParameters.xml

   Project.Web.SourceManifest.xml

   Project.Web.zip
```

3)On this step I need to start cmd as administrator on the server

My question is: on this 3th step what kind of command i need to write to make the publish on the Website(the site is like serveName/project/...)

In the moment I have a work web site for example myServername/myProjectname.This site is intranet and is using only inside the corp.I make changes localy in the project and now i have this file on the top picture and I need to "update" this site from this Publishing.Sorry for bad explanation but i did`t make this before and don`t know how i need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the site name in step 1 when you setup the publish profile.

[image]

Run the *.deploy.cmd without any parameters and it will open a readme file with further details how to run the cmd.

Comment: But i use on Publishi method : Web Deploy Package

Comment: I don't understand what that means.  Can you add a screenshot to your question or provide more details?